# Trying to compile winsock program in dev C++ win7 - error

Tags: c++, winsock, linker-errors, imp

I try to compile this http://www.nongnu.org/cpirc/

I have got errors like : (when linking)

```
118     IRC.cc  undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
123     IRC.cc  undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
```

I dont know how to fix problem in visual i dont have this erros (but i want to compile it in dev c++)

I try to find solution on internet, but there are not solution for dev c++ (i dont saw)

Answer (score 2):

```
118     IRC.cc  undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
123     IRC.cc  undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
```

You don't seem to have correctly linked to the [Windows Socket 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) library called `ws2_32.lib`.

Try adding `-lws2_32` to the linker options.